# Interpretar html desde la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, express

Buenas comunidad de programadores, solicito una pequeña ayuda con un pequeño problema que tengo al mostrar el valor de contenido de mi aplicación web.

Usando el editor tinymce, he guardado el contenido de un post en una celda de la base de datos (Maria DB).
por ejemplo

publicación.post = `<strong>Hola mundo</strong>`

El paso siguiente es obviamente leer la base de datos para mostrar al publico ese contenido. Sin embargo al momento de escribirlo el resultado es

```
<div class="publicacion">{{mipost.post}}</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir el código no se interpreta. Me gustaría saber como hacer para que se interprete y no quede como texto plano.

Algunos datos extra.

- trabajo con NodeJS y Handlebars
- Utilicé Javascript con el modo innerhtml y las anticomillas `{{mipost.post}}`. Sin embargo aún así sigue mostrando texto plano.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping), cuando encierras la variable entre llaves dobles `{{ variable }}` el contenido es interpretado (o escapado) para convertir caracteres especiales en entidades html, resultando `<` en `&lt;`.

Para mostrar directamente el código HTML, sin modificar, debes encerrar la variable entre llaves triples: `{{{ variable }}}`

```
<div class="publicacion">{{{mipost.post}}}</div>
```

Una llave adicional soluciona el problema.

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo este mundo de las aplicaciones web. Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. Funcionó!